# Scalability Testing Tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, scalability

I have developed MVC4 Web API. There will be around 100 of concurrent users using this app. Is there any tool to test for scalability which makes 100 HTTP Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend SOASTA: http://www.soasta.com/products/soasta-platform/.

It will use Amazon EC2 to send requests to your API, possibly from various geographical locations (using separate EC2 datastores).